# How can I prevent Tornado from hanging up on SQLAlchemy transaction errors?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, tornado

I am currently using a SQLAlchemy's `scoped_session` and calling `db.close` in `on_finish` in tornado. Will this cover all if not most errors? I don't want to put every DB transaction in a try/except. My other thought was to create a connection pool. Will that prevent more errors or be simpler?